# Assembly Digital Lab Sim Calculator

Tags: assembly, calculator

anyone can have me with this.

calculator:

Use Digital Lab Sim to build a calculator. Provide `+`,`-`,`*`,`/`:

- `a` for `+`
- `b` for `-`
- `c` for `*`
- `d` for `/`
- `f` for `=`

Specific:

- When you hit a number, it displays in LED, only display 2 bottom numbers. Ex: press `1` display `01`, then press `2` display `12`, if press `3` display `23`.
- after press number, press `+`,`-`,`*`,`/`
- press `f`(`=`) to show the result to LED.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We don't do your homework for you. What have you tried? Please show some effort.

Comment: well i tried to display the number and scan for interrupt when you press.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .eqv SEVENSEG_LEFT 0xFFFF0011 # Dia chi cua den led 7 doan trai. 
                # Bit 0 = doan a; # Bit 1 = doan b; ... 
                # Bit 7 = dau . 
.eqv SEVENSEG_RIGHT 0xFFFF0010 
                # Dia chi cua den led 7 doan phai 
.text 
main: 
    li $a0, 0x6 # set value for segments 
    jal SHOW_7SEG_LEFT # show 
    li $a0, 0x7F # set value for segments 
    jal SHOW_7SEG_RIGHT # show 

exit: li $v0, 10 
    syscall 

endmain: 
#--------------------------------------------------------------- 
# Function SHOW_7SEG_LEFT : turn on/off the 7seg 
# param[in] $a0 value to shown # remark $t0 changed 
#--------------------------------------------------------------- 
SHOW_7SEG_LEFT: li $t0, SEVENSEG_LEFT # assign port's address 
    sb $a0, 0($t0) # assign new value 
    jr $ra #--------------------------------------------------------------- 
# Function SHOW_7SEG_RIGHT : turn on/off the 7seg 
# param[in] $a0 value to shown # remark $t0 changed 
#--------------------------------------------------------------- 
SHOW_7SEG_RIGHT: li $t0, SEVENSEG_RIGHT # assign port's address 
    sb $a0, 0($t0) # assign new value 
    jr $ra

display can but i dont know how to hit a button then display it.
```

Comment: Please paste code this into the question text, since it's not an answer. So, have you tried debugging? Which line doesn't work as expected?